# Aren't Named Pipes in the Filesystem slow?

Tags: memory, filesystems, pipe, ipc, named-pipes

Isn't it useless to write stream data for IPC into a file in the filesystem and so on to your (HDD o. SSD)? I mean, isn't it better to create a "buffered" pipe in the memory, so that we have more performance on the drive? But I'm new in IPC... or isn't it writing onto the disk? But how is this possible that the system writes into the filesystem without writing into a disk?

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking the use of named pipes to actually see if they're slow?

Comment: Nope, because I've never done stuff with it before. This question helps me to decide if I will learn more about pipes or if want to use other things for IPC.

Comment: Note this is a similar to the [Does named pipe modify the filesystem?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81334/does-named-pipe-modify-the-filesystem) question over on the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Aren't Named Pipes in the Filesystem slow?

They're no slower than any other sort of pipe.

> isn't it better to create a "buffered" pipe in the memory

If you aren't memory constrained, then yes (see older OS link below).

> [...] or isn't it writing onto the disk?

Your guess is correct - on many modern operating systems data going into a named pipe is not being written to the disk; the filesystem is just the namespace that holds something that tells you where the ends of the pipe can be found. From the Linux [man page for pipe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html#DESCRIPTION):

> Note: although FIFOs have a pathname in the filesystem, I/O on FIFOs does not involve operations on the underlying device (if there is one).

There are [older operating systems that buffer pipe data within a filesystem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/450900/109111) but given your question's phrasing (on such systems ALL pipes go through the filesystem not just named ones) I suspect this is a tangent.